# Work with Eclipse helios and Weblogic server10g

Tags: weblogic, eclipse-3.6

I have installed Weblogic server10g and Eclipse helios on my Windows 7 but when I'm selecting new runtime for the dynamic web project it doesn't show Weblogic server.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Open your eclipse, switch to the Java EE view (if not yet at it), and go to the "Servers" tab (if not open, go through the menu: Window->Show View->Servers).
Right-click the Servers panel, and then go to the New->Server menu.
Look for already existing installations of Weblogic plug-ins, under the Oracle folder. If you do not have any Weblogic plug-in yet, click "Download additional server adapters".
Wait for the list to load and then select "Oracle Weblogic Server Tools" from the list and click "Next".
Make sure you go through the licenses, agree with them and then accept the agreement and click "Next" (applying default values all the way through the end of the wizard, if applicable).
Now, right-click again your "Servers" panel, and click "New->Server" again. Scroll down to the "Oracle" folder and select the correct version of your Weblogic installation (probably "Oracle WebLogic Server 10gR3", according to your question).
Set the "Weblogic home" with the home folder of your Weblogic instance (the default is C:\Oracle\Middleware[wlServer_VERSION_#] on Windows operating system).
On the next screen, leave every configuration at its default, but be sure to select your Domain directory. Click "Finish".
Your Weblogic runtime should now be available for selection.

Comment: can we select any directory for Domain directory ? what is use of this directory.

Comment: @Vipin you should have already created a Domain before adding your server to the Eclipse installation. Please refer to [WebLogic Domains overview](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/adminguide/overview_domain.html) for additional information.